# Not loading Icons from react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, font-awesome

Are you guys having problems with the react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome today ? I'm using a react-native version >0.6 so i don't think the problem is about linking.

As you guys can see in the picture it doesn't show any Icon that i'm asking for, i don't know what is going on...

this is the picture of what is showing on my android emulator:
[Print-Scream-Icon-Not-Showing-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBFNZ.png)

```
import React from 'react'
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'



export default function ActionButton(props) {

    return(
        <TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.container}>
           
           <Icon name='plus' size={30} color='#777' />
           <Icon name='trash' size={30} color='#777' />
           <Icon name='search'  size={30} color='#777' />
        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center',
        width:80,
        height:40,
        backgroundColor:'#FFF',
        elevation:9,
        marginTop:20,
        borderRadius:6,
        paddingVertical:15,
        marginBottom:10
       
    }
})
```

Comment: `react-native-vector-icons` doesn't support `AutoLinking`, so you still need to manually add native module by urself, or use this command `npx react-native link react-native-vector-icons` and re-run android command to build your apps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

so the library `react-native-vector-icons` doesn't have a support for the Auto-Link on react-native > 6.0 it means that you must run the command `npx react-native link react-native-vector-icons` to link, after linking re-run the android emulator and everything will work fine. !. Special thanks for the anonymous who helped me with the answer !!!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using expo, you can write it like this:

```
import { FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";

<FontAwesome name="dollar" size={60} color={"green"} />
```

Comment: Isn't the name "faDollar"?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try add loadFont function like that?

```
import React from 'react'
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'

Icon.loadFont(); // <- Add this line


export default function ActionButton(props) {

    return(
        <TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.container}>
           
           <Icon name='plus' size={30} color='#777' />
           <Icon name='trash' size={30} color='#777' />
           <Icon name='search'  size={30} color='#777' />
        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center',
        width:80,
        height:40,
        backgroundColor:'#FFF',
        elevation:9,
        marginTop:20,
        borderRadius:6,
        paddingVertical:15,
        marginBottom:10
       
    }
})
```